Gaussian Process Literature suggestion
I'm quite new to Gaussian Process and hope to get some help regarding the materials to read up on here. Suppose I have the following 2d time series data table:
$$\begin{bmatrix}s_{t_1}^{v_1} & s_{t_2}^{v_1} & \ldots & s_{T}^{v_1} \\ s_{t_1}^{v_2} \\ \vdots & & \ddots \\
s_{t_1}^{V} & \ldots &&s_{T}^{V}\end{bmatrix}$$
where $t, v$ are 2 different time indexes. I have two questions:

Suppose the "row-wise" time series (in index $t$) has a clear pattern and can be modeled using a Gaussian Process and a stationary kernel function. The "column-wise" time series (in index $v$) also does, but the pattern implies a different kernel. Is there a method to model the whole matrix jointly in this setting? If so, what are they called? (I'm vaguely thinking of something like a $k_1 \times k_2$ kernel for modeling any two items in the matrix but not sure if this exists/does what I'm looking for)
Suppose the "row-wise" time series still have nice patterns as above, but the "column-wise" time series do not have such a nice pattern. Specifically, assume that the values are not independent, there is, say, strong seasonality observed through ACF plot, at different lags, for different columns. Is there any study on a form of kernel function that lets us incorporate these signals/seasonality (could be in the form of indicator variables)? In a way, I'm thinking of something like: conditioning on these signals (by means of differencing etc), the items in a column are independent and we bring the columns back to a nice consistent pattern (random walk for example). We can model all columns by this one kernel and they will take into account all the discrepancy.

Would love to discuss further, appreciate any suggestion you guys have, thanks!

brief semi-answer: 1) tensor product kernel 2) put seasonality info not in the kernel, but in the mean function.
